# Letter combinations between a string in a list

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, combinations

I'm trying to compare the difference of a given string to a list. Precisely I'm trying to compare a given word, if **only one letter** of the word was different, to my list of words.

```
list = ['fake','bake','sake','rake'] #probably a set
```

If given word was `take` then the result would return `fake bake sake rake`

If the word was `bare` then the return is `bake`

The way I'm planning to do this is to split the given word into and start a loop to interchange every letter of this word with a list of the dictionary (a,b,c's). With every iteration of my loop, I plan to check if this word is in my list of words.

I calculated for just a 4 letter word, I would have to do about 26^4 loops in order to check every letter combination to match my list of words.

---

Can someone show me an efficient way to check combinations of a word?

Comment: May be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: You might edit your candidate list so not all the words match. Otherwise it is hard to test if an algorithm works ;^) Also, will the candidates always have the same number of letters as the target?

Comment: If one of the words in the list **is** the given word, do you want it included in the result?

Comment: @wwii No, it shouldn't include itself but that's simply a `if` condition if word is not itself then append... or is there a better way to do that

Comment: @czi I just wanted to be sure that the functions in my answer behaved correctly.

Comment: @czi did you look at the wikipedia article Blender posted.  I like that.

Comment: I like the wikipedia article that @Blender posted (and implemented the matrix solution) but looks like it does len(word1) * len(word2) operations per comparison.

Comment: @wwii Yes levenshtein's algorithm is perfect for my solution. I've looked into it, it doesn't require importing any libraries and it well known overall for string matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jellyfish library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jellyfish/0.1.2) can calculate a whole host of distances between words. It will probably be better to use this wheel rather than inventing one of your own.

From the example page:

```
>>> import jellyfish
>>> jellyfish.levenshtein_distance('jellyfish', 'smellyfish')
2
>>> jellyfish.jaro_distance('jellyfish', 'smellyfish')
0.89629629629629637
>>> jellyfish.damerau_levenshtein_distance('jellyfish', 'jellyfihs')
1
```

So applied to your question:

```
import jellyfish
target = 'take'
list = ['teak','fake','bake','sake','rake','sale']
outlist = [x for x in list if jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(x,target) == 1]

print outlist
['fake', 'bake', 'sake', 'rake']
```

Comment: -1 for the library. This function is very easy to implement, just a single expression: `len(s1) == len(s2) and sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a != b)`

Comment: Fine for a simple case, but I disagree in general. What value does your approach give for `snake` and `bake`?

Comment: Pardon me. I was wrong. Levenshtein distance works differently than I first thought.

Comment: No problem. I agree about simplicity!

Comment: But my code works for OP's problem. Think I'll just post it as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the word against each of the base words, letter by letter. Increase a counter on each difference found and keep track of the words with 0 or 1 differences. This is linear in the number of base words, much better than your exponential approach.

Here is a reference implementation:

```
def atMostOneDifference(word):
    matching = []
    for baseWord in ['fake','bake','sake','rake']:
        distance = 0
        if len(word) != len(baseWord):
            continue
        # We take the i-th letter from word and baseWord...
        for letter, baseLetter in zip(word, baseWord):
            if letter != baseLetter:
                distance += 1
        if distance <= 1:
            matching.append(baseWord)
    return matching
```

Comment: What's zip checking for? Mind commenting your second for statement please?

Comment: It takes the letter in the same (increasing) position from both words at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = 'take'
matches = []
candidate_list = ['fake','bake','sake','rake']
for candidate in candidate_list:
    differences = 0
    for (original_word_letter, candidate_word_letter) in izip(word, candidate):
        if original_word_letter != candidate_word_letter:
            differences += 1
        if differences > 1:
            break
    else:
        matches.append(candidate)
```

This uses the relatively obscure [`else`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) clause on the for loop, which is not executed if the loop exited due to a `break`, and assumes that the word lengths are all equal - testing for non-equal lengths is of course straightforward.

It's a bad idea to use built-in names like `list` for your own variables - they're not informative and they will hide the built-in meaning within the appropriate scope.

Answer (score 0):

I like slices myself.
Use a function that returns True/False to filter the list for the conditions you need/want.

```
orig = 'abcdef#ghijklmn'
test = 'abcdef%ghijklmn'
test_bad = 'abcdef%ghijk*mn'

def one_letter_different(s1, s2):
    """returns True if there is only one letter different between s1 and s2.

    Sequentially check each letter of each string till they don't match
    then check to see if the rest of the strings are equal.

    s1, s2 -> str
    """
    for i, c in enumerate(s1):
        if c != s2[i]:
            # test for substituition, deletion and insertion
            return (s1[i + 1:] == s2[i + 1:] or
                    s1[i:] == s2[i + 1:] or
                    s1[i+1:] == s2[i:])
    # s1 equals s2
    return False

print one_letter_different(orig, test)
print one_letter_different(orig, test_bad)

test = 'take'
print [item for item in ['fake','bake','sake','rake']
       if one_letter_different(item, test)]

test = 'bare'
print [item for item in ['fake','bake','sake','rake']
       if one_letter_different(item, test)]
```

Produces:

```
>>> 
True
False
['fake', 'bake', 'sake', 'rake']
['bake']
>>>
```

The compare function could also be defined as:

```
from operator import ne
from itertools import izip_longest

def one_letter_different(s1, s2):
    """returns True if there is less than two letters different.

    Sequentially compare the letters of each string and sum the differences.

    s1, s2 -> str
    """
    return sum(ne(*thing) for thing in izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue = None)) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple expression which returns number of different letters or `False` if strings have different length:

```
len(s1) == len(s2) and sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a != b)
```

And in your case:

```
target = 'take'
list = ['fake','bake','sake','rake']

def diff(s1, s2): 
    return len(s1) == len(s2) and sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a != b)

print [word for word in list if diff(word, target) == 1]
```