# All pair comparison of string values in two dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dictionaries, dict1 and dict2. Dictionary contains key as an ID and value as an string. I need to perform all pair comparison of all the values in dict1 with all other values in dict2.

I am using the following code which is working fine but it is very slow. My actual data contains approximately 100,000 values in each dict. Is there any other 'efficient' way to do the same.

```
import difflib
dict1 = {"111": "asdfa", "222":"gdjkgd", "333":"xvbkx"}
dict2 = {"311": "asdfa", "322":"gdjkzxgd", "333":"xvvbkx"}
qKeys = sorted(dict2.keys())
#Write the header in outfile
nline = "ref"+ "\t" + "\t".join(qKeys) + "\n"
print(nline)
for item in dict1:
    ratioArr = []
    refseq = dict1[item]
    for qitem in qKeys:
        qSeq = dict2[qitem]
        myratio = round(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, refseq, qSeq).ratio(),2)
        ratioArr.append(str(myratio))
    #print(myratio)
    nline = item + "\t" + "\t".join(ratioArr)+"\n"
    print(nline)
```

Comment: I would consider using a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe). You could have an index for the ID (dict key in your example). Then perform an outer join operation and apply a function that does the comparison to the result. Of course there will be ways to do it with `dict`, but it seems like you really need a bit of relational logic on the IDs followed by application of an arbitrary piece of code (the comparison operations). That's what Pandas is good at.

Comment: Thanks @EMS, would you mind giving a simple example on how to do this.

Comment: One of the distance metrics (jaro, perhaps) in the `jellyfish` library would probably apply. Here is an [example answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259553/letter-combinations-between-a-string-in-a-list/19259729#19259729) that prints out words of a certain distance, but you could just as easily print out the distance itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is, firstly, using something faster than difflib, which is pure python.

You should check if you can use the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). If you can, you could use [pylevenshtein](https://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/).

Finally, you have the problem of deciding which string matches which - that's a [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). It can be efficiently solved using the [hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). A commonly used implementation of this algorithm is [munkres](http://software.clapper.org/munkres/) .

Comment: thanks, The pylevenshtein package is more than a magnitude faster than difflib `SequenceMatcher` function. I used the `ratio` function present therein.